# Sending Json raw content from ASP .Net Core controller

Tags: c#, json, .net, asp.net-core, controller

I want to send raw Json content in a string on ASP .Net Core controller output.

If I try to do it by returning the string itself double quotes in its content will be escaped and the client will not recognize it as a Json content but as a string. Eg. :

```
public async Task<ActionResult<MyClass>> Get()
{
    try
    {
        // here we build an object from a service with a complex dataset
        MyClass myObject = ...;  // business code here
        // serializing the object
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
        {
            WriteIndented = true,
            ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles
        };

        string jsonDataset = JsonSerializer.Serialize<MyClass>(myObject , options);
        // or we could do simply for testing something like: jsonDataset = "{\"Id\"=10, \"Label\"=\"HelloWorld!\"}";
        // then we send it to the client
        return Ok(jsonDataset);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I cannot deserialize the json, it is too complex with object lists referencing other objects.

I cannot use NewtonSoft library, it is a no-go for my project's client. So no anonymous class for deserialization here :[|]

Is there a way to output the string "jsonObject" as an application/json content *BUT WITHOUT* double-quote escaping ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you just want to `return Ok(myObject);`

Comment: I'd use: public async Task<JsonResult> Get() ... then return new JsonResult(new {Data=YourModel})...

Comment: Thanks Robert, the Ok(myObject) was failing because of circular references in the object. Serialization needed option `ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles` to work

Comment: Thanks pcalkins, it might work but with the option I mentionned in my previous comment may be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Content` methods to return the string and specify the content type:

```
return Content(
  jsonDataset, 
  "application/json");
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I finaliy found something by re-reading the IActionResult docs with the JsonResult. I finaly simply used: return Json(myObject, options); With the options ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles serializing the object in controller output worked. Thanks again though :)

Comment: Marcus, your solution works too :)